# Cannot make any network request (fetch) in react-native 0.63.4 (Android)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I just started developing with react native for the first time, it's a simple android app I created with react-native init command (not using expo this time).

I'm trying to make a simple network request but for some reason it's not firing at all, if I check the network tab in chrome devtools react-native debugger I can clearly see no network request is firing at all, I tried with axios instead of fetch and still nothing. I run the app in my plugged android device with npx react-native run-android command.

I added INTERNET permissions to AndroidManifest.xml file too.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

In my App.js I have:

```
useEffect(() => 
    {
        console.log('App mounted');
        tryAsyncFetch();
    }, []);

const tryAsyncFetch = async () => 
    {
        try
        {
            console.log('Fetching from placeholder...');
            fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
            .then((response) => console.log('response',response.json())); 
        }
        catch (e) 
        {
            console.error(e);
        }    
    };
```

As you can see it's pretty simple but it's not working, if I check the network tab no XHR requests at all, no error in catch segment, nothing...

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tAEFd.png

I can see the logs before the fetch (Fetching from placeholder...) but no console logged results, this is SO WEIRD...

When I used expo I remember fetch/android working perfectly

EDIT 1: When I console log axios after importing it like

```
import axios from 'axios'
```

I get this back:

```
ƒ wrap() {
      var args = new Array(arguments.length);

      for (var i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
        args[i] = arguments[i];
      }

      return fn.apply(thisArg, args);
    }
```

I don't think that' what I'm supposed to get back

Comment: Are you using `axios` or the `fetch` api?. Are you getting any error message?. Have you done anything to see the network requests in your chrome browser?.